# Add subquery on annotate with the model field value from the same model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a model as follows:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent_job = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Now I need to get the name of the parent model in an `annotate`.

I have tried the following but to no success:

```
(
    Job.objects.filter()
    .annotate(
        par_job_name=Subquery(
            Job.objects.filter(id=OuterRef("parent_job")).first().name
        )
    )
    .values("id", "par_job_name")
)
```

```
(
    Job.objects.filter()
    .annotate(
        par_job_name=Subquery(
            Job.objects.filter(id=F("parent_job")).first().name
        )
    )
    .values("id", "par_job_name")
)
```

How can I get the `par_job_name` here?

Note: I know that using a `foreignkey` to `self` might be a good way to model here but this is existing code and I have to work with this for now. So I have to implement the solution for the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the docs, I came to know that I was using `OuterRef` the wrong way. I had to first create a queryset and then pass it to `Subquery` so that it can be resolved by the outer queryset.

```
parent_job_qs = Job.objects.filter(id=OuterRef("parent_job"))
(
    Job.objects.filter()
    .annotate(
        par_job_name=Subquery(
            parent_job_qs.values('name')
        )
    )
    .values("id", "par_job_name")
)
```

Note: I will still wait for a better answer for sometime. If I do not get any response then I will mark this as the correct answer.